# Having problem in comparing two string variable in Python

Tags: python, variables

So I am writing a python program for creating a cricket scoreboard. Now I am having problems while comparing strings. This may be a dumb question I know, but here is my code

```py
print("\nWelcome to our Cricket Score Board program")
team1 = input("Enter team 1 name: ")
team2 = input("Enter team 2 name: ")

print("Do the toss")
whoWonTheToss = input("Who won the toss: ")
print(whoWonTheToss)

if (whoWonTheToss != team1) or (whoWonTheToss != team2):
    print("Enter a valid choice")
```

I did `print(whoWonTheToss)` just to check if my program is working. I am not the best at explaining but here is the output that I am getting

```
Welcome to our Cricket Score Board program
Enter team 1 name: RCB 
Enter team 2 name: CSK
Do the toss
Who won the toss: RCB
RCB
Enter a valid choice
```

Now I am thinking why the program is giving me `Enter a valid choice` in the end after winning the toss. This should end the program, but instead it is just prinint Enter a valid choice. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I ended up doing using the `==` operator instead of `!=`
But I need the proper solution to that (so that's why not add in the answer your question.

``` python
Here is my code:
if (whoWonTheToss == team1) or (whoWonTheToss == team2):
    print("Let's move there")
else:
    print("Enter a valid choice")

Note the above code is the same

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` instead of `or` to check this -

```
if (whoWonTheToss != team1) and (whoWonTheToss != team2):
    print("Enter a valid choice")
```

You don't get correct output, because `or` checks only one of the conditions, you need to check if both of them are equal

Comment: Thanks this is working!